# How to find IE mode in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, jsp

In my web application i am trying to get the IE mode(Quirks or Standard) using JSP.

If the mode is Quirks i need the style as `style="display:inline"` and if the mode is Standard the style should be `style="display:inline-block"` for a html list

Comment: IE mode is on the client, not the server. JSP runs on the server.

Comment: I guess he needs a javascript to check in which mode IE is.

Comment: you make it quirk using JSP, not check the quirks with JSP...

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript function [document.compatMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533687%28VS.85%29.aspx) and load different CSS stylesheet.

In a general way, if document is valid the mode is standard.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can find that as JSP runs on the server side and IE mode is on the client side.

With javascript you can probably use `navigator.userAgent` to find the version

or may be you can try `document.documentMode`.